# Insert current date in datetime format mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems getting the date inserted properly into my database.

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
```

I use this format, and, it echoes out correctly, however, when, I insert

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table 
(dateposted) 
VALUES ('$date')");
```

it doesn't appear to work successfully, and, the time remains 00:00:00
If you could find the solution that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Dateposted is the datetime format.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

If you're looking to store the current time just use MYSQL's functions.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES (now())");
```

If you need to use PHP to do it, the format it `Y-m-d H:i:s` so try

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES ('$date')");
```

Comment: But it'll use MySQL server locale/timezone. If U have Apache/PHP and MySQL on different servers and timezone set incorrect in one of them U'll have different values.

Comment: @Jeff_Alieffson is right. Using `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) is preferred instead of `NOW()`

Comment: I tried same but I am getting 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and my datatype is datetime. any help in this?

Comment: Would be great to use PDO instead of mysql_query(), wouldn't?

Answer (score 39):

Try this instead

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 8):

`NOW()` is used to insert the current date and time in the MySQL table. All fields with datatypes `DATETIME, DATE, TIME & TIMESTAMP` work good with this function.

YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS

Demonstration:

Following code shows the usage of `NOW()`

```
INSERT INTO auto_ins
(MySQL_Function, DateTime, Date, Time, Year, TimeStamp)
VALUES
(“NOW()”, NOW(), NOW(), NOW(), NOW(), NOW());
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, mysql function

Answer (score 6):

set the `type` of column named `dateposted` as `DATETIME` and run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table (`dateposted`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 2):

"[datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)" expects the date to be formated like this: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

so format your date like that when you are inserting.

Comment: So I would do date("YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS", time());?

Comment: No? use dashes(-) not slashes (/).

Answer (score 1):

```
     <?php $date= date("Y-m-d");
$time=date("H:m");
$datetime=$date."T".$time;
mysql_query(INSERT INTO table (`dateposted`) VALUES ($datetime));
?>

<form action="form.php" method="get">
<input type="datetime-local" name="date" value="<?php echo $datetime; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

If you Pass date from PHP you can use any format using `STR_TO_DATE()` mysql function .
Let conseder you are inserting date via html form

```
$Tdate = "'".$_POST["Tdate"]."'" ;    //   10/04/2016
$Tdate = "STR_TO_DATE(".$Tdate.", '%d/%m/%Y')"  ;  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES ('$Tdate')");
```

The `dateposted` should be mysql `date` type . or mysql will adds 00:00:00
in some case You better insert date and time together  into DB so you can do calculation with hours and seconds . () .

```
$Tdate=date('Y/m/d H:i:s') ; // this to get current date as text .
$Tdate = "STR_TO_DATE(".$Tdate.", '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')"  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make it easier and efficient is this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
field1,
..
..
time_updated timestamp default current_timestamp
)
```

Now, when you insert a row into table, you can skip this field (`time_updated`) as it will fill with current time as default value

Answer (score 0):

Just use with your timezone :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');      
$date=date("Y/m/d h:i:sa");
```

Answer (score 0):

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
with the type: 'datetime' worked very good for me as i wanted to print whole date and timestamp..

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmtc->bindParam(2,$date);

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what datatype you set for your db table.

#### DATETIME *(datatype)*

MYSQL

```
INSERT INTO t1 (dateposted) VALUES ( NOW() )
// This will insert date and time into the col. Do not use quote around the val
```

PHP

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
INSERT INTO t1 (dateposted) VALUES ( '$dt' )
// This will insert date into the col using php var. Wrap with quote.
```

#### DATE *(datatype)*

MYSQL

```
INSERT INTO t1 (dateposted) VALUES ( NOW() )
// Yes, you use the same NOW() without the quotes.
// Because your datatype is set to DATE it will insert only the date
```

PHP

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d');
INSERT INTO t1 (dateposted) VALUES ( '$dt' )
// This will insert date into the col using php var.
```

#### TIME *(datatype)*

MYSQL

```
INSERT INTO t1 (dateposted) VALUES ( NOW() )
// Yes, you use the same NOW() as well. 
// Because your datatype is set to TIME it will insert only the time
```

PHP

```
$dt = date('h:i:s');
INSERT INTO t1 (dateposted) VALUES ( '$dt' )
// This will insert time.
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe, you need to change your code little bit like follows alongside with your database filed type.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (`dateposted`) VALUES ($datetime)");
```

Hope, will work perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

use this

`$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());`

and then 
in MYSQL do

`type=varchar`

then date and time will be successfully inserted

Comment: your first function is the same as used in the question. And the rest of this answer doesn't warrant reopening a 5 year old question. Please explain why you think your solution is better than those that were posted 5 years ago.

Comment: because in old question not explain about data type

Answer (score -5):

Try this

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', new Date('<?=$value->fecha_final?>'));
```

Comment: This will set a jQuery datepicker.  The question was about inserting into a MySQL database.