# Converting a column to timestamp or datetime and querying the latest within a time interval

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a database dumped from csv where i have a column name time_stamp that I imported using VARCHAR

I have two things that I am confused about now,

1) I want to be able to convert this column to either timestamp or datetime 
 its current format is in dd/mm/yyyy H:M:S but i read that unix accepts only **-** instead of **/**. Is this true?

2) I want to query from the database a timestamp value that is the highest within a certain time range using the column above

Example: between 7 AM and 8 AM , it should give me the timestamp which will be the closest to 8AM

Forgive me for my question if my question is vague, but i haven't been able to find much related to my question. I am sure that this is gonna receive some down votes so please be kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few things.. first look here to see more about the date format. [Insert current date in datetime format mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541029/insert-current-date-in-datetime-format-mysql)

second you should probably update the table to change the / to a -.

use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert

to get the most recent date then just do this

```
SELECT MIN(date) FROM table -- // MIN() is used to get the most recent timestamp
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c/%e/%Y %r') BETWEEN $start AND $end
```

start and end would be your starting and ending dates

---

IF YOU ONLY WANT TO CHECK OFF OF THE TIME OF THE DAY USE THIS:

```
SELECT MIN(date) FROM table -- // MIN() is used to get the most recent timestamp
WHERE TIME(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c/%e/%Y %r')) BETWEEN $start AND $end
```

---

per my previous recommendation you should update the table like this.

```
UPDATE table
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c/%e/%Y %r')
```

something like that to fix it ... that will make your querys less complicated :)

Comment: I need to make it for for a certain time period, will this work for that as well ?

Comment: yes if you put the starting date as the start variable and ending date as the end variable

Comment: sorry, my question may not have been correct. I want to query data from a certain time interval eg: 7 to 8 AM everyday and want to get data from a timestamp which will be closest to 8 AM, so can i query something like SELECT MIN(date) FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN 7:0:0 AND 7:59:59

Comment: @Bazinga777 i just edited with the conversion on the date to compare. try it

Comment: Oh so you don't care what day it happens on? just the hour?

Comment: @Bazinga777 ok just edited to check off of time.. try that :)

Comment: @Bazinga777 i added an update to my answer as well so you can change the values in the database as well.. that will make the query's much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, that is true. Date needs to be `YYYY-mm-dd H:M:S`. (you can convert it in php and then do an `insert (date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($your_date))))`

2)

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE HOUR(date) BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date'
GROUP BY DAY(date)
ORDER BY DAY(date)
```

Comment: You can also use: date('c', strtotime($your_date));

Comment: I dont think the first option is a possibility as it would affect the performance of my application as I have about 10 million rows of data.

Also, can startdate and end_date be replaced by a certain time period meaning any number of days but a certain time period 

say 7AM and 8AM everyday

Comment: sure, but you need HOUR(date) BETWEEN 'start_hour' AND 'end_hour' in that case

Comment: Ok, so i can just query hours instead of dates? is that what you mean ?

Comment: That's what you asked, isn't it ?

Comment: I believe you want to do MIN() instead of MAX() because dates are inverted... MAX() gives you the oldest date.. MIN() gives you the most recent :)

Comment: he wants the Highest in a time range